# How to process Avro messages while reading a stream of messages from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The below code reads the messages from Kafka and the messages are in Avro so how do I parse the message and put it into a dataframe in Spark 2.2.0?

```java
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "topic1")
            .load();
```

This https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro library had no example for streaming case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I parse the message and put it into a dataframe in Spark 2.2.0?

That's your home exercise that is going to require some coding.

> This https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro library had no example for streaming case.

I've been told (and seen a couple of questions here) that spark-avro does **not** support Spark Structured Streaming (aka Spark Streams). It works fine with non-streaming Datasets, but can't handle streaming ones.

That's why I wrote that this is something you have to code yourself.

That could look as follows (I use Scala for simplicity):

```scala
// Step 1. convert messages to be strings
val avroMessages = df.select($"value" cast "string")

// Step 2. Strip the avro layer off
val from_avro = udf { (s: String) => ...processing here... }
val cleanDataset = avroMessages.withColumn("no_avro_anymore", from_avro($"value"))
```

That would require developing a `from_avro` custom UDF that would do what you want (and would be similar to how Spark handles JSON format using `from_json` standard function!)

---

Alternatively (and in a slightly more advanced? / convoluted approach) write your own custom streaming [Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source.scala) for datasets in Avro format in Kafka and use it instead.

```java
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.readStream()
            .format("avro-kafka") // <-- HERE YOUR CUSTOM Source
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "topic1")
            .load();
```

I'm yet to find out how doable `avro-kafka` format is. It is indeed doable, but does two things at once, i.e. reading from Kafka **and** doing Avro conversion, and am not convinced that's the way to do things in Spark Structured Streaming and in software engineering in general. I wished there were a way to apply one format after another, but that's not possible in Spark 2.2.1 (and is not planned for 2.3 either).

I think then that a UDF is the best solution for the time being.

---

Just a thought, you could also write a custom Kafka [Deserializer](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html) that would do the deserialization while Spark loads messages.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking more like this `sparkSession.readStream().format("kafka").schema(convertAvroSchemaToStructType).option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").load()`

Comment: Impossible. Schema is static and is either applicable to a dataset or not. Period. I fixed my answer and am sure that you should do `from_avro` as Spark does `from_json`.

Comment: so `from_avro` should take `Column` and `StructType` as arguments and return a `Column` ? If so, I would have to convert the schema to struct type and I am wondering if I could leverage this https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-4.0/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala#L44 function ?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what any UDF does -- takes a `Column` and gives another `Column`. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

Comment: Got it. But converting from Avro `Schema` object to `StructType` doesn't seem trivial. Even the spark-avro library seemed to have made some choices on how it would handle different types in various cases. Is there any source or any help I could get on this?

Comment: No idea...if spark-avro is not giving you answers about schema conversion I doubt you may find better sources. That's your home exercise :) Also, you could use StackOverflow to dig deeper and find a solution, right. But that's another question and this seems to be answered, doesn't it? Accept it if so :) Thanks!